# xctest activate not working when ran from command line

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest

In the application, we launch Maps and to get back to the application from our XCTest, we use `app.activate()`.  This works perfectly when running the test from XCode.  However when we run the tests from command line using `xcodebuild`, it does not work.  It gets stuck on the Maps page and will not return to the app.  Does anyone know why or a workaround?

We also tried to press the home screen first and then activate the application, but it won't background the maps app to go to the home screen either.

```
XCUIDevice().press(XCUIDevice.Button.home)
app.activate()
```

That also works in XCode but does not work via command line.

I'm using XCode 10.3.

Comment: would you please provide the compilable code to research a bug?

Answer (score -1):

I did more research and determined this is a problem with using SBTUITunnel for mocking so I posted a question here.  https://github.com/Subito-it/SBTUITestTunnel/issues/91.